# How does Guzzle send async web requests?

Tags: php, guzzle

`cURL` is synchronous. So how do libraries like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) send asynchronous web requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/)'s transport handlers is [`CurlMultiHandler`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php) that uses PHP's [`curl_multi_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) functions which allows for asynchronous transfers.

The requests are launched asynchronously and the function [`curl_multi_select()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) allows `Guzzle` to wait until one of the curl requests receives data and process it.

Answer (score 5):

The [Guzzle CurlMultiHander](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php) wraps PHP's builtin [curl_multi_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) function which essentially wrap the [cURL Multi API](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html)

From the cURL documents:

> To use the multi interface, you must first create a 'multi handle' with curl_multi_init. This handle is then used as input to all further curl_multi_* functions.
>
> With a multi handle and the multi interface you can do several simultaneous transfers in parallel. Each single transfer is built up around an easy handle. You create all the easy handles you need, and setup the appropriate options for each easy handle using curl_easy_setopt.